# Queue of tasks for parallel computing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing

The outline of what I want to do is as follows:

```
#function to be run about 6k times, doesn't return anything
someFunction <- function(integer,string)
{...}
#parameters to be passed
params <- data.frame(ints=1:6000, strings=...)
#number of cores the system has
numCores <- detectCores()

count <- 1;
#run while there are still tasks to be run and there is a free core
while(count <= 6000 && <# of running tasks < numCores>)
{
   count <- count + 1;
   <assign someFunction(params$ints[count],params$strings[count]) to free core>
}
```

The two pieces of code in <> brackets are where I am not sure how to proceed. I am on a Ubuntu system, so I can use the multicore package.

I suspect I may need an integer to keep track of how many cores are being used and when a process finishes, it simply subtracts one from this integer and a new process adds one, or maybe an array of length `numCores` to keep a 0 or 1 if it's being used or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use either the multicore or snow packages.  With snow, you can accomplish what you are after pretty simply:

```
clust<-makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterExport(clust,"someFunction") ## added on edit, see comment by Steve Weston
clustFun<-function(i,params){someFunction(params$ints[i],params$strings[i])}
clusterApply(clust,1:6000,clustFun,params)
```

This will evaluate the calls in parallel and assign the results to a list of length 6000.  You can also use `clusterApplyLB` which performs load-balancing similar to what you are describing.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html

Comment: This code fails for me because `someFunction` hasn't been exported to the cluster.  Also, `detectCores` isn't defined in `snow`: it's in `parallel`.

Comment: @Steve Weston:  Good point on both counts.  `clusterExport(clust,someFun)` needs to be called.

Answer (score 4):

The parallel programming packages in R tend to be higher level than what you describe.  Since you're not using Windows, you can use the "multicore" API in the `parallel` package:

```
library(parallel)
someFunction <- function(int, string) {
  paste0(string, int)
}
params <- data.frame(ints=1:6000,
                     strings=rep(letters, length.out=6000))
numCores <- detectCores()

r <- mcmapply(someFunction, params$ints, params$strings,
              SIMPLIFY=FALSE, mc.cores=numCores)
```

This returns 6000 results in the list `r`.

Another option is the `foreach` package.  In your case, I recommend `doMC` since it also uses the "multicore" API in the `parallel` package.  First you load and register `doMC`:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(numCores)
```

Then you use `foreach` and `%dopar%` to call `someFunction` in parallel, returning the results in a list:

```
r <- foreach(i=params$ints, s=params$strings) %dopar% {
  someFunction(i, s)
}
```

In both cases you don't directly manage how the tasks are scheduled on the cores.  By default, both examples *preschedule* the tasks which is generally more efficient if the tasks all take the same length of time to compute, but that can be turned off if load balancing is desired.

Answer (score 1):

These approaches using `%dopar%` and `foreach()` or `times()` from the `foreach` package also ensure your iterations are started in sequential order. They are similar to the `clusterApply` approach described by @mrip.

### doParallel and doSNOW approach

If you want to use `doParallel` or `doSNOW`, `foreach` will balance the load by **not** pre-allocating each iteration to the cores. (Disclaimer, I am testing this on a multicore Mac).

Tested here:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# or 
# library(doSNOW)
# cl <- makeCluster(2, type="SOCK")
# registerDoSNOW(cl)

foreach(i=1:6, duration=c(1,2,5,6,1,1), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
    start=Sys.time()
    Sys.sleep(sleep_durations[i])
    c(index=i, pid=Sys.getpid(), duration=sleep_durations[i], start=start, end=Sys.time())
}
stopCluster(cl)
         index   pid duration      start        end
# result.1     1 97167        1 1495651947 1495651948
# result.2     2 97175        5 1495651947 1495651952
# result.3     3 97167        2 1495651948 1495651950
# result.4     4 97167        6 1495651950 1495651956
# result.5     5 97175        1 1495651952 1495651953
# result.6     6 97175        1 1495651953 1495651954
```

---

## doMC approach

If you are using `doMC`, `times(n) %dopar% { code block }` will run the code block `n` times. This will allocate to available cores, rather than dividing up the number jobs evenly per core (which is what @steve-weston's `doMC` package does during `foreach`).

The problem here is `times()` does not allow you to specify iteration-dependent parameters. Furthermore, `doMC`'s environment-forking does not allow you to write to shared memory.

If you are working on a single node, it may be possible to use the filesystem as your locking mechanism for tracking iterations.

```
lock <- tempdir(); dir.create(lock)  # Empty dir before re-running the loop
times(6000) %dopar% { 
#   Sys.sleep(runif(1));  # Uncomment if lock fails (iteration sequences contains skips, followed by repeats, e.g. 1, 3, 3, 4) in attempt to stagger processes 
    file.create(file.path(lock, runif(1)));  # Filename can be anything, but must be unique
    count <- length(list.files(lock));
    someFunction(params$ints[count],params$strings[count])
}
```

Tested here:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=2)
sleep_durations <- c(1, 5, 2, 6, 1, 1)

napVerbosely <- function(pid, duration) {
    print(sprintf("[pid %s] Sleeping for %s sec", pid, duration))
    Sys.sleep(duration)
}

lock <- tempdir()
dir.create(lock)
times(6) %dopar% {
    file.create(file.path(lock, runif(1)));
    count <- length(list.files(lock));
    napVerbosely(Sys.getpid(), sleep_durations[count])    
}
# [1] "[pid 96874] Sleeping for 1 sec"
# [1] "[pid 96875] Sleeping for 5 sec"
# [1] "[pid 96874] Sleeping for 2 sec"
# [1] "[pid 96874] Sleeping for 6 sec"
# [1] "[pid 96875] Sleeping for 1 sec"
# [1] "[pid 96875] Sleeping for 1 sec"
# NULL
```